# Can't install Modules in Spyder

Tags: python, spyder

I have a problem with installing modules in spyder (4.2.5). When I try to install them through the consol I get this message.

pip install tk
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
Der Befehl "C:\Users\David" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
konnte nicht gefunden werden.

Which translates to. #The command "C:\Users\David" is either written false or couldn't be found.#

To note is that my Users name is not "David" but "David Ermecke". I reinstalled it already.
Anyone a idea what is happening?

Comment: Could you check if there is a folder named David on C:\Users?

Comment: There is not a folder named "David" on C:\Users but one named "David Ermecke"
which should be the correct one

Comment: If you have Spyder, you may probably also have Anaconda. If that's the case try using "conda install package" in the terminal instead. Mixing up pip install and conda could potentially mess up your installation.